# Which mathematical objects retained the names given by their discoverer(s)?

Tags: mathematicians

Many mathematical objects and even theories are named after people, and most of the people with mathematical things named after them did not name said things after themselves. There is the famous anecdote that in a seminar David Hilbert had to ask what a "Hilbert space" was. Presumably Hilbert called it something else.

In fact, mathematics is full of things named after people. A very short and nowhere near complete list include the following:

- [Tate modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_module) ;
- [Cartier divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Cartier_(mathematician));
- [Selberg sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_sieve);
- [Grothendieck ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-ring);
- [Hardy space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space), etc.

Of course, there are also many mathematical objects with very mundane names. What are some examples of mathematical objects, preferably those involved in active areas of research, which retained the names given to them by their discoverers?

Comment: e.g., Baire space, Dedekind cut/domain, Germain prime, Mersenne number, Fermat number, Riemann integral, Lebesgue integral, Fourier transform

Comment: You mean like Leibniz's "function", Hamilton's "vector", Dedekind's "field", Grothendieck's "topos" and "motive", and Mandelbrot's "fractal"? There are too many.

Comment: Eilenberg-Mac Lane's _category_, _functor_ and _natural transformation_; fundamental notions in Category Theory (which is still an active field of research). See their 1945 article _"General Theory of Natural Equivalences"_ for reference.